# Ethereum data reading and writing time fluctuation for web3

Tags: web3js, javascript, ropsten, ethereumjs

I have created a web app for sending and receiving data in ropsten testnet.
The average result of writing Data to the blockchain and reading it. The average is calculated for 5 transactions.
Here data input is an integer list.
Now the writing time and reading time varies as the size of array is changed. **I want to know why the writing time is decreasing while increasing data volume. And also for the 60 input data takes more time to write. Similarly for reading time why the 120 input data is taking less time to read compared to the others. Can I know why the fluctuation of data reading and writing time?**

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|Data Input Per Minute|  Avg. Txn Writing|  Gas Cost(wei)   | Avg. Data Reading|
|    (Size of array)  |   Time (seconds) |                  |   Time (seconds) |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          6          |        24.2      |      236576      |       2.61       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |        19.6      |      359289      |       3.36       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          60         |        28.8      |      1340996     |       4.68       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         120         |        19.3      |      2568142     |       2.31       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         360         |        18.1      |      6268877     |       4.39       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I have collected the data using:
**clientside.js**

```
i1.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    await fetch('/sensor/createData?sensorId=0&data=0').then(response => {
        response.json().then(data => {
            m1.textContent = 'TxnHash: ' + data.sdata.transactionHash + '\n\n Gas Used: ' + data.sdata.gasUsed;
        })
        t2 = performance.now();
        td1.textContent = (((t2 - t1) / 1000).toPrecision(3)).toString() + ' seconds';
    })
})
i2.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    await fetch('/sensor/createData?sensorId=0&data=1').then(response => {
        response.json().then(data => {
            m2.textContent = 'TxnHash: ' + data.sdata.transactionHash + '\n\n Gas Used: ' + data.sdata.gasUsed;
        })
        t2 = performance.now();
        td2.textContent = (((t2 - t1) / 1000).toPrecision(3)).toString() + ' seconds';
    })
})
i3.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    await fetch('/sensor/createData?sensorId=0&data=2').then(response => {
        response.json().then(data => {
            m3.textContent = 'TxnHash: ' + data.sdata.transactionHash + '\n\n Gas Used: ' + data.sdata.gasUsed;
        })
        t2 = performance.now();
        td3.textContent = (((t2 - t1) / 1000).toPrecision(3)).toString() + ' seconds';
    })
})

i02.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    await fetch('/sensor/createData?sensorId=0&data=3').then(response => {
        response.json().then(data => {
            m02.textContent = 'TxnHash: ' + data.sdata.transactionHash + '\n\n Gas Used: ' + data.sdata.gasUsed;
        })
        t2 = performance.now();
        td02.textContent = (((t2 - t1) / 1000).toPrecision(3)).toString() + ' seconds';
    })
})
i05.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    await fetch('/sensor/createData?sensorId=0&data=4').then(response => {
        response.json().then(data => {
            m05.textContent = 'TxnHash: ' + data.sdata.transactionHash + '\n\n Gas Used: ' + data.sdata.gasUsed;
        })
        t2 = performance.now();
        td05.textContent = (((t2 - t1) / 1000).toPrecision(3)).toString() + ' seconds';
    })
})

d1.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    await fetch('/sensor/getData').then(response => {
        response.json().then(data => {
            d2.textContent = "DataID: " + data.sdata[0] + "\nSensorId: " + data.sdata[1] + "\ndata: " + data.sdata[5];
        })
        t2 = performance.now();
        td.textContent = (((t2 - t1) / 1000).toPrecision(3)).toString() + ' seconds';
    })
})
```

The method calling function is like bellow:

```
async function asyncGetLatestData() {
    return await contract.methods.getLatestData().call();
}
```

The driver function is [web3.js](https://pastebin.com/GW2hwmM8)

Comment: You're not taking into account any lag between you and the node (i.e., your "internet speed"), as well as anything that happens on the node itself (for example, other requests by other users), as well as any lag between the node and the other nodes (i.e., the node's "internet speed").

Comment: You're assuming that these factors are constant, so they should yield the exact same impact every time you measure the execution time of some contract function. But they are not.